# Crystal Report Group Header not visible on every page

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a group header which contains the column names for the data in the details section. I am trying to display the group header on every subsequent page since my data in the details section is too much.

I have tried enabling the "Repeat group header on each page option" but still no help. Also tried many other solutions posted on the web. Doesn't seem to help.

My report structure is similar to the below:

```
Report Header

Page Header

GH1

 -GH1a

 -GH1b

Details

 -GF1b

 -GF1a

Report Footer

Page Footer
```

I am trying to show the group header for GH1b. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Group header will be displayed on change of every group..

Since your detail data is huge group header won't be carried to next page where there is no change in group.

One wayout would be place all columns of `GH1b` on the page header so that it appears on every page and write the code to `supress` the `page header` when group changes that is when `GH1b` appears.

Hope this solution helps.